# Is this function monotonically decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Fix $t \leq T$.
$$f(n):= \frac{e^{nt}-e^{-nt}}{e^{nT}+e^{-nT}-2}$$

Is $f$ monotonically decreasing in $n$?

I tried derivating it but it didn't really help me.. please help me out.

Comment: $$\frac{e^{nt}-e^{-nt}}{e^{nT}+e^{-nT}-2}=\\\frac{2sinh(nt)}{2cosh(nT)-2}=\\\frac{sinh(nt)}{cosh(nT)-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f\left(  n\right)    & =\frac{e^{nt}-e^{-nt}}{e^{nT}+e^{-nT}-2}\\
& =\frac{e^{nT}\left(  e^{2nt}-1\right)  }{e^{nt}\left(  e^{2nT}%
+1-2e^{nT}\right)  }\\
& =\frac{e^{nt}+1}{e^{nt}}\frac{e^{nT}}{e^{nT}-1}\frac{e^{nt}-1}{e^{nT}-1}%
\end{align*}
The first function $\frac{e^{nt}+1}{e^{nt}}=1+e^{-nt}$ is decreasing. The
second function $\frac{e^{nT}}{e^{nT}-1}=\frac{e^{nT}-1+1}{e^{nT}-1}%
=1+\frac{1}{e^{nT}-1}$ is decreasing. So we just need to show $\frac{e^{nt}%
-1}{e^{nT}-1}$ is decreasing. Set $x=nt$, $a=\frac{T}{t}\geq1$, it is enough
to show
$$
g(x)=\frac{e^{ax}-1}{e^{x}-1}\text{ is increasing.}%
$$
We have
\begin{align*}
g^{\prime}(x)  & =\frac{ae^{ax}\left(  e^{x}-1\right)  -e^{x}\left(
e^{ax}-1\right)  }{\left(  e^{x}-1\right)  ^{2}}=\frac{\left(  a-1\right)
e^{ax}e^{x}-ae^{ax}+e^{x}}{\left(  e^{x}-1\right)  ^{2}}\\
& =\frac{\left(  a-1\right)  e^{ax}-ae^{\left(  a-1\right)  x}+1}
{e^{-x}\left(  e^{x}-1\right)  ^{2}}=\frac{h\left(  x\right)  }{e^{-x}\left(
e^{x}-1\right)  ^{2}}%
\end{align*}

$$
h^{\prime}(x)=a\left(  a-1\right)  e^{ax}-a\left(  a-1\right)  e^{\left(
a-1\right)  x}\geq0
$$
so
$$
h\left(  x\right)  \geq h\left(  0\right)  =0
$$
so
$$
g^{\prime}(x)\geq 0
$$
so
$$
g(x)=\frac{e^{ax}-1}{e^{x}-1}\text{ is increasing.}%
$$

Answer (score 1):

As in the 1st comment, $f(n)=\frac{\sinh(nt)}{\cosh(nT)-1}$. We differentiate this, and we only consider the numerator, as the bottom is the square of a real number, so is positive (we will assume non-zero). The numerator is 
$$t(\cosh(nT)-1)\cosh(nt)-T\sinh(nT)\sinh(nt)$$
We take the derivative of this as well to give
$$tT\sinh(nT)\cosh(nt)+t^2\sinh(nt)\cosh(nT)-t^2\sinh(nt)-T^2\cosh(nT)\sinh(nt)-tT\sinh(nT)\cosh(nt)$$
This is
$$\sinh(nt) \cdot (t^2\cosh(nT)-T^2\cosh(nT)-t^2)$$
Here we're going to assume that n>0, but you could choose to work in n<0 and apply a similar process. We will also assume $0\leq t\leq T$, which I presume was the intended question? Otherwise, we could consider the more complex situation without this restriction on $t,T$, but it is not that much more difficult.

We now have $\sinh(nt)>0$, so we need to look only at the sign of
$$t^2\cosh(nT)-T^2\cosh(nT)-t^2$$
But $t\leq T$ and $\cosh$ is strictly greater than 0, so this term is negative always. We evaluate the numerator found above at 0 to get 0, so we know that the numerator is less than 0. So $f$ has a negative derivative, so is a decreasing function.